# How to find correct neighbors for any giving coordinate?

Tags: java, algorithm, coordinates

Update: this question is seeking guidance on how to get a set of neighbors for any given coordinate.

I created a 2d array that contains coordinates,

```
 int[][] coordinates= { { -1, -1 }, { -1, 0 }, { -1, +1 },
            { 0, -1 }, { 0, +1 }, { +1, -1 }, { +1, 0 }, { +1, -1 } };
```

As you can tell, these are the neighbors for coordinates (0,0).

Now I am trying to implement a method that takes two parameters `(int positionX, int positionY)`, and use the input parameters value coordiante(x,y) as the starting coordinate and find all the neighbors for this coordinate.

I am thinking about something like this:

```
    int getNearCoordinates(int positionX, int positionY) {

        for (int[] coordinate: coordinates) {
               //I am not sure what to do after this
        }

    }
```

I am trying to use a loop to get the individual coordinate from the 2d array I created and I am stuck at here. How do I find a way to appropriately find positionX's and positionY's neighbor?

**What are neighbours?**

All orange points in diagram below are neighbours of Origin `(0,0)`
[image]

Comment: Do you want to calculate the distance of two coordinates (returning an `int`) or do you want to get the set of neighbours to a coordinate (returning eight coordinates)?

Comment: @slartidan i want to get the set of neighbors.

Comment: Is this an algorithm question? I.e. how can I do this with the best time complexity? or space complexity? If so, let's not cloud the issue with Java just yet. OTOH, if you already have an algorithm and just need help coding it in Java, please post the algorithm you'd like to use.

Comment: I'm unclear on exactly what you want. Do you want to generate the set of 8 coordinates that are the neighbors of the point you input? Or are we trying to determine which of a known set of coordinates are neighbors to the point you input? Or something else?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom i want to get a set of neighbors for a any given coordinates. Sorry about unclear, I will update my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend to

- Use a dedicated **class** (`Coordinate`) instead of `int[]`. This makes your code easier to extend (3rd dimention, etc) or to change (using `double` instead of `int`, etc.). In the example you can see an **imutable** class - this hinders code to have side effects.
- Use `Collection` instead of `Array`. This makes handling much easier (you can simply `add` and `remove` items)
- Use **java8-Streaming-API**. It is lightning fast and makes your code better readable.

Additional ideas:

- You could even make `getNearCoordinates` part of the Coordinate class. This would make `new Coordinate(27,35).getNearCoordinates()` available.
- Instead of storing `x` and `y` in separate fields you could also use a `Map<Axis, Integer>`. This would make your code a little bit harder to understand - but would reduce duplicated code.
- You could also *generate* the collection of directions by using two nested loops `for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) use(new Coordinate(x,y))`. This would make your code *cleaner*, but might be harder to understand.

Example code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Snippet {

    // make a class to be more flexible
    class Coordinate {

        // final fields are making this an "imutable"
        final int x;
        final int y;

        /** constructor to take coordinate values */
        Coordinate(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        /** moves this coordinate by another coordinate */
        Coordinate move(Coordinate vector) {
            return new Coordinate(x + vector.x, y + vector.y);
        }
    }

    /** using Collection instead of Array makes your live easier. Consider renaming this to "directions". */
    Collection<Coordinate> coordinates = Arrays.asList(
            new Coordinate( -1, -1 ), // left top
            new Coordinate( -1,  0 ), // left middle
            new Coordinate( -1, +1 ), // left bottom
            new Coordinate(  0, -1 ), // top
            new Coordinate(  0, +1 ), // bottom
            new Coordinate( +1, -1 ), // right top
            new Coordinate( +1,  0 ), // right middle
            new Coordinate( +1, +1 )  // right bottom
            );

    /** @return a collection of eight nearest coordinates near origin */
    Collection<Coordinate> getNearCoordinates(Coordinate origin) {
        return
                // turn collection into stream
                coordinates.stream()

                // move the origin into every direction
                .map(origin::move)

                // turn stream to collection
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

Same behaviour without Java8-streaming API would look like this:

```
/** @return a collection of eight nearest coordinates near origin */
Collection<Coordinate> getNearCoordinates(Coordinate origin) {
    Collection<Coordinate> neighbours = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Coordinate direction : coordinates)
        neighbours.add(origin.move(direction));

    return neighbours;
}
```

Comment: I really like this answer, however I am not allowed to use Java 8 in this assignment, only Java 7

Comment: @HashMap I added a "non-Java8" implementation

Comment: I have a question, the `getNearCoordinates` method returns a collection of type `Coordinate`, what should I do if I want to get the exact value of those coordinates? For example, for  coordinate of (1,1), how do I get all the 8 neighbor coordinates like this:(1,0),(0,0),(2,0),(2,1),(3,1),(2,3),(0,2),(0,1)?

Answer (score 4):

Two points **A(x1,y1)**, **B(x2,y2)** are neighbours if this expression is true:

```
 Math.abs(x1-x2) <= 1 && Math.abs(y1-y2) <= 1
```

Here if both differences are equal to zero then **A** equals **B**.

Comment: Please keep in mind, that the task is to evaluate the **set** of neighbours - not to tell whether or not a certain coordinate **is** a neighbour.

Comment: Hi, what would this condition be if I wanted to exclude diagonal neighbors?

Answer (score 1):

*This is not the best way to implement it (using int[] for points), the purpose of this answer is to show the algorithms*.

If you are talking about an unbounded plane then you will always have 8 points, so you could implement it the following way:

```
// first point index, 2nd: 0 = x, 1 = y
public int[][] getNeighbours(int x, int y) {
   int[][] ret = new int[8][2];
   int count = 0;
   for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
      for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
         if (i == 0 && j == 0)
            continue;
         ret[count][0] = x + i;
         ret[count++][1] = y + j;
      }
   return ret;
}
```

**It gets more interesting if the plane is bounded**, using an ArrayList this time:

```
public List<int[]> getNeighbours(int x, int y, int minX, int maxX, int minY, int maxY) {
   List<int[]> ret = new ArrayList<int[]>(8); // default initial capacity is 100
   for (int i = Math.max(x - 1, minX); i <= Math.min(x + 1, maxX); i++)
      for (int j = Math.max(y - 1, minY); j <= Math.min(y + 1, maxY); j++) {
         if (i == x && j == y)
            continue;
         ret.add(new int[] {i, j});
      }
   return ret;
}
```

The latter will work for any point, also outside of the plane or just at the border.

Comment: Just saw, if you don't like the `continue` it can be rewritten as `if (i != x || j != y) ret.add(...);`

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you define a neighbour. The code below will test the coordinates and return true for the diagonal as well as horizontal and vertical neighbours.

```
if (Math.abs(coordinate[0] - positionX) <= 1 && Math.abs(coordinate[1] - positionY) <= 1)
{
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(coordinate));
}
```

make sure to import `java.lang.Math`

Printing of the coordinates is just an example of course, but may be useful for debugging.

Comment: Hi, what would this condition be if I wanted to exclude diagonal neighbors?

Answer (score 0):

It may seem obvious, but you could duplicate `coordinates`, and add the given coordinate's x and y values to those of each coordinate, fit example using a for loop.