# Efficient Way To Find Neighboring Coordinates In R

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, optimization

I am working with a matrix data set that has X-Y coordinates, and rest of the columns have logical values containing different parameters. I want to find the neighboring coordinates of X-Y given at least one of the corresponding parameters is true, and then append it to new matrix as rows. Below is the sample matrix data.

**Data_1**

```
  X  Y  P1 P2 P3 P4
-52  32  1  0  0  1
-50  34  0  0  0  0
-50  26  0  0  0  1
-52  31  0  1  1  1
```

To solve this, I am planning to use following algorithm:

**Algorithm**

```
# Find row wise sum
newCol <- rowSums(Data_1)

# Bind as first column with Data_1
newData <- cbind(newCol, Data_1)

# Not R code, pseduo code
if (newData[,1] != 0{
    store newData[,2] and newData[,3].
    Data_2 <- find neighboring coordinates to newData[,2] and newData[,3].
}

finalData <- cbind(Data_1, Data_2)
```

**Output**

```
  X  Y  P1 P2 P3 P4 N1.x N1.y N2.x N2.y N3.x N3.y N4.x N4.y N5.x N5.y N6.x N6.y N7.x N7.y N8.x N8.y
-52  32  1  0  0  1      <Neighboring Coordinates---->
-50  34  0  0  0  0      <NULL>
-50  26  0  0  0  1      <Neighboring Coordinates---->  
-52  31  0  1  1  1      <Neighboring Coordinates---->
```

The problem with this approach is scalability when the matrix will have millions of rows and columns.

Following image shows neighbor coordinates for `(x,y)`.

Please suggest better approach if possible, thanks.

Comment: For your example data, what would go in columns N1.x, N1.y, N2.x, N2.y, ...?

Comment: `newCol <- t(t(newCol))` this turns your matrix from original, to its transpose vertical, to original again in the exact format it was prior to this step....

Comment: @EricWatt - For first row with `-52, 32`, `N1.x, N1.y, N2.x, N2.y....`, will be all 8 neighbor coordinates. Similarly for other rows.

Comment: @sconfluentus - Thanks. I thought if `dim(newCol)` is `NULL`, then I need to make it column and then append using `cbind()`, but I did make it into original form with another `t()` as you pointed. Fixed the pseudo code.

Comment: I don't know what 'all 8 neighbor coordinates' means. Can you show the output you expect for the first 4 rows?

Comment: @EricWatt - Please check updated question. I have added the image which should explain what neighbor coordinates mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a data frame approach--does it need to be a matrix?

```
# Create one data frame with the starting points
points <- data.frame(x = c(-52, -50, -50, -52), 
                     y = c( 32,  34,  26,  31))

# Create a second data frame with the desired combinations of distances
distances <- expand.grid(xd = 1:4, 
                         yd = 1:4)

# Repeat the distances for each point (cartesian product/outer join)
neighbors <- merge(points, distances) 

# Compute neighbor coordinates
neighbors$nx <- neighbors$x + neighbors$xd
neighbors$ny <- neighbors$y + neighbors$yd

# sort
neighbors <- neighbors[order(neighbors$x, neighbors$y), ]

# display
head(neighbors)
```

Result

```
     x  y xd yd  nx ny
4  -52 31  1  1 -51 32
8  -52 31  2  1 -50 32
12 -52 31  3  1 -49 32
16 -52 31  4  1 -48 32
20 -52 31  1  2 -51 33
24 -52 31  2  2 -50 33
```

Comment: .@Damian - Thanks. I fetch the data from a file and treat it as `matrix`, so far haven't worked much with `data.frame`. Also, why in your output `x-y` has multiple neighbors with same coordinates?

Comment: The previous post had repeated values because the x-y points were duplicated by `expand.grid`. In this version I created the x and y in a separate data frame

Comment: .@Damian - Your suggestion make sense, but it calculates distance for all the combination of `x-y` for `1-4`?

Comment: Correct. That was for the sake of demonstration of the general process. (1) construct a data frame with one row per point-to-neighbor (or neighbor distance) combination, (2) compute the position of the neighbor the pair of points on each row. Any set of distances could be used.

Comment: .@Damian - There is [one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764233/how-to-find-correct-neighbors-for-any-giving-coordinate), but in `Java`. I was wondering there may be an approach to this with `apply()` for larger data set.

Comment: I can't really interpret the java solution. Are the calculations in the suggested data frame correct? It would be helpful to have data in the  example of the desired result. Also, if you prefer apply-based solutions, you could try using vectors (for x, y, and distances) as input parameters to a multivariate function using `mapply`